# Snowflake throwing error (Error parsing JSON: misplaced { )

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load json files in to snow flake using copy command.I have two files of same structure.However one file loaded without issue,the other one is throwing the error
"Error parsing JSON: misplaced { "

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the JSON file and the COPY INTO command used? Error suggests you might have an extra **{** in your JSON file.

Comment: You can copy the text of the one JSON file and paste it into https://jsonlint.com. This will validate the JSON or report any errors it finds in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

The simple example `select parse_json($1) record from values ('{{');` also errors with `Error parsing JSON: misplaced {, pos 2` so your second file probably does in fact contain invalid JSON.

Try running the statement in validation mode (e.g. `copy into mytable validation_mode = 'RETURN_ERRORS';`) which will return a table containing useful troubleshooting info like the line number and character of the error(s).

The docs cover this here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#validating-staged-files